# Does node JS support ESC POS printing?

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, escpos

With the help of Electron, I intend to build a cross platform desktop app using AngularJS and NodeJS as client side and server side frameworks respectively.

There is a need to be able to print receipts to a standard POS printer and also product bar-codes. I was wondering whether this is possible in NodeJS or if there are such solutions available on GitHub.

Comment: In general, "Does X do Y" (Yes / No) style questions are too broad for this format.  What you are *really asking* is how to accomplish the task, not if the task can be done.  Therefore, it's better to directly ask about the part of the process you are having trouble with, and provide as much detail as possible about what you have tried, instead of hoping that someone might throw a ready made solution your way at random.

Comment: That being said, it feels like even your starting point is a bit misplaced here;  In a client/server environment it is much more likely that you want to print from the client than print from the server, so looking for a way to have Node talk to the printer seems misguided.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I apologize for asking too broad of a question. I'd be happy to figure the "how" part myself. I was just curious if someone has already done it. Also, correct me if I am wrong here, I don't think Javascript based apps can directly communicate with printers especially if ESC/POS commands need to be passed.

Comment: I think the nodejs modul escpos is doing what you'r looking for. It supports linux and windows. Electrons main process is a nodejs server, running on client side. So yes you can access all devices with js. @Claies with electron you'r on client side.